Rename-Computer not working after upgrading to Windows 11
I use a short, simple script when I occasionally have to change a PC name.  It worked without any flaws for the last year while using Windows 10.  Recently upgraded to Windows 11 and have had trouble with the script since.  Even weirder, it's worked intermittently for me and a couple others.  I tried running it several times last week with the same error.  I ran it today and it worked.
$OldName = Read-Host "Please Enter the Current Computer Name"

$NewName = Read-Host "Please Enter the New Computer Name"

$User = "username"

Rename-Computer -ComputerName $OldName -NewName $NewName -DomainCredential domain\$user -Restart

Read-Host "Press Enter to Restart $NewName"

If I right click the script and Run with Powershell it works sometimes and other times throws the error pictured below.  It looks like it doesn't like the format of the domain credential to me but I don't know.
If I run it in ISE it works every time.
Execution policy is unrestricted and defender credential guard is not enabled.
Error:

$PSVersionTable when I wrote the script:

$PSVersionTable I'm running now:


Is it prompting you for the credential? In PS v5.1, that should open up a "enter your credentials" prompt, and closing/canceling/hitting escape will generate the error you're seeing for example. You could try adding $cred = Get-Credential -UserName "domain\user" before, and then -DomainCredential $cred instead, and see if it behaves any different?

It does prompt you for your credentials and the way it's used here the username portion is already filled out and you just enter your password.  BUT when it does throw this error it never throws the credentials prompt, just straight to this error.
I tried the script again just now and it worked.  The next time it gives the error I will try using your $cred variable.  Could this error be caused by some domain issue?  It looks like a formatting error to me

I tried the script again this morning and this is the following error if you close/cancel/hit escape on the credentials box. Rename-Computer : Cannot establish the WMI connection to the computer 'ags-tmp06jd-lp' with the following error message: Access is denied.

It's basically just failing to coerce the string domain\username into a [pscredential] object, which is supposed to prompt you like normal. The prompt failing to appear sometimes sounds like buggy behavior... what's the output of $PSVersionTable in the terminal? Any chance the PCs have some updates pending, or are you always running this from the same local PC?

Definitely buggy, no pending updates and myself and the other user always run it from the same machine.  I added pics of the $PSVersionTable to the post

Yeah I'm not sure what it's problem could be unless you can figure out when it works/fails. You might be able to get around it by using $pass = Read-Host "password for $user" -AsSecureString instead (uses a different prompt), then manually create the credential: $cred = [pscredential]::new("domain\$user",$pass), then rename like Rename-Computer -DomainCredential $cred
